# Laravel pagination with orderby doesnt work well

Tags: laravel

There's a problem about laravel paginate with orderby.

```
$products->with(['cover'])
    ->orderBy('priority', 'asc')
    ->paginate(12);
```

Code above returns different result then code below;

```
$products = $products->with(['cover'])
    ->orderBy('priority', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

All the first 12 records are different.
Whats wrong with it?

Comment: i have tested it in local with 5 records and paginating 3 .both return correct result.not sure how it will be different .bit curious about your issue.

Comment: In the first code it seams like you have already retrieve `Products` from database and `$products` in that case will be a `Collection` and not an instance of `Query` Builder